# Chaining servlet filer with jersey filter

Tags: servlets, filter, jersey

My jersey filter is identified with the @Provider annotation. Myweb.xml defines my servlet filters alone. I notice that my servlet filters are always executed before my jersey filter. I am unable to define my jesery filter in web.xml. How do I specify the ordering of the filters?

I want my jaxrs jersey filter to be executed before AuthFilter, but it is always executed after AuthFilter.

My jax rs jersey filter class is annotated with @Provider (com.sq.filters is the package which has this jersey filter)

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Sq</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/views/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.SqListener</listener-class>
    </listener>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ApiServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.json,
                com.sq.api,
                com.sq.filters,
                com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON,
                com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.JerseyApiDeclarationProvider,
                com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.JerseyResourceListingProvider
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ApiServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>




     <filter>
        <filter-name>Webapp</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sq.webcommon.SqWebApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex</param-name>
            <param-value>/sq/static/.*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!--
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
            <param-value>/(decorators|scripts|styles|resources|(WEB-INF/views))/.*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sq.webcommon.SqWebApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
         pass to next filter if Jersey/App returns 404 -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Webapp</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/sq/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sq.auth.AuthFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Please show your web.xml

Comment: My jersey filter is annotated with @Provider and not explicitly defined in web.xml . I just added it in web.xml as above, but that does not work for me

Comment: Please edit your post with this information. And not in a comment

Comment: Done.. Please check web.xml. I would like my jersey filter to execute before the auth filter (which is a plain servlet filter), but I am not able to achieve that,

Comment: _"I would like my jersey filter to execute before the auth filter "_. That's not going to happen. This is just how it works. No way around it. This is just the natural order of execution. Filters happen before Jersey. Write a Servlet filter if you want it before the auth filter, or make the auth filter a Jersey filter also

Comment: Ok, thanks! Just wanted to confirm one q. Is the only way to specify ordering among jersey filters the use of @Priority annotation?

Comment: For your situation, yes. If you use a ResourceConfig for your configuration (instead of in the web.xml), you can `register(yourfilter, priorty)`